# Conditional reuse of Global SQL temp table in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to reuse a temporary table in a SQL SERVER stored procedure in more than one place to collect data from three possible database and insert the data into one of two target databases. Can this be done?

The scenario is that I would like to query 1 of 3 possible databases depending on a parameter, insert the collected data into a temporary table then retrieve it to use in an insert statement in one of two target tables. The insert will again rely on a parameter. I will use the two tables in a reporting solution (SSRS)). The report will compare the two tables to identify differences. I know I could write it all long hand but I was trying to keep the code manageable

Some example code

```
Declare @Switch varchar(11)='A'
Declare @Target varchar(11)='1'

--create tables
Create Table TargetTable1 (Date datetime)
Create Table TargetTable2 (Date datetime)

If @Switch ='A' 
Begin 
    Drop Table ##TestTemp
    --pull data from database 1
    Select GETDATE() Date into ##TestTemp
End

If @Switch <>'B'
Begin
    Drop Table ##TestTemp
    --pull data from database 2
    Select dateadd(d,10,GETDATE()) Date into ##TestTemp
End

If @Target=1 
Begin
    Insert Into TargetTable1
    select * from ##TestTemp 
End
If @Target<>'1'

Begin
    Insert Into TargetTable2
    select * from ##TestTemp 
End
```

When I try I get

> > Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 There is already an object named '##TestTemp' in the database.

Thanks

Comment: Your `DROP` command isn't being committed before your `SELECT INTO`. Try putting a BEGIN / END around your `DROP` command or explicitly commit after your `DROP`, before your `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: Ok yes I can see that (now)

Comment: I have changed the drop statement to.  'BEGIN TRANSACTION;  Drop Table #TestTemp; 
 COMMIT TRANSACTION;' But the error is the same

Comment: It is frustrating when stuff looks like it should work, but doesn't. At this point, I might consider a strategy change: Only select-into if the table doesn't exist. Otherwise, trunc table and insert/select.  For sure, you are better-off if you can figure-out why this should-work-but-doesn't. ...but if you have timeline pressure ...